# jQuery Mobile run script after elements are rendered

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am attempting to move some icons around dynamically on a jquery mobile page.  The script works, but at the time when it runs, the position of every element is at 1.  I've read the jquery documentation that talks about pagecreate, pageshow, etc, but I can't get any of them to work to run the script after the elements are rendered in their place.

My page is being created in a layout.cshtml like this:

```
<div id="mainPage" data-role="page">...</div>
```

And the script with varying uses of pagecreate/pageshow is:

```
  $("#mainPage").live("pageshow", function () {
       $(".folderIcon").each(function (i) {
            var parentTop = $(this).parent().parent().position().top;
        });
    });
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors? Are you sure you have a `class` on various elements of `'folderIcon'`? If you're not sure break on it in your browser's Developer Tools or put an `alert("hey!")` in there.

Comment: Is that script nor running or is not repositioning the elements?

Comment: No javascript errors.  Yes.  As I mentioned the script works.  I can watch it a console and it iterates through each element fine.  But the position of every element is returned as 1 because while the page HTML is loaded, the elements aren't rendered yet.

Comment: Jack, the script is running, and it is technically repositioning the elements, the problem is that it doesn't reposition them where they are supposed to go.  The script looks for the parent divs and gets their positions.  Then it moves the elements being looped to relative to their parents.  The issue is that they are being moved to their exact same spot because when I get the position of the parent (see script) it returns 1.

Comment: I'm not allowed to answer my own question but here was the solution:  $(window).load(function () {
            $(".folderIcon").each(function (i) { //move icons });

Comment: @user1404184 You should be allowed to answer your own question, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6593/limiting-self-answers

Comment: @user1404184 Another thing, in the future if you use the @ symbol when replying to someone in the comments they get a notification http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work